# Not getting value in session

Tags: vb.net, session

I am using  session and assigning  hidden field value to   a session

```
Dim row = grid_transfer.Rows(Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument))
 hid_refno = CType(row.FindControl("hid_refno"), HiddenField)
Session("refno") = hid_refno.Value
```

but it is not showing value in session

Comment: So you have debugged this code to verify that `hid_refno.Value` contains something and one line later `Session("refno")` returns `Nothing`? I doubt it. Mabye you are overwriting this value somewhere, but then you haven't shown that code. Where do you assign it and where do you read it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use session value in a page we have to use

```
session("refno").tostring();
```

then it will display the assigned value.`